# Phusion Passenger + (Rails + Drupal) = unable to deliver Drupal app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drupal, nginx, passenger

I'm having trouble getting Phusion Passenger to serve a Rails app as well as a Drupal app, which live on the same server.

The Rails app lives in ~/Kiji and the Drupal app lives in ~/asia-gazette, as shown in the config below.

When I try running `curl kiji.dev` I get the Rails app, which is correct. When I try running `curl eag.dev` (the Drupal app) from the server I am getting a 200 response with nothing else. No output, nothing in the nginx error.log file.

Below is what my nginx.conf file looks like at the moment (note that I set the user for nginx as www-data so that it can be used by php5-fpm)

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.48;
    passenger_ruby /home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen              80;
        server_name         kiji.dev;
    passenger_enabled   on;
    root   /home/dani/Kiji/public;
       location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
       expires max;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
       gzip_static on;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
 }

    server {
      listen 80;

      root /home/dani/asia-gazette;
      server_name   eag.dev;

      location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
      }

      location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
      }

      # This is needed for Drush
      location = /backup {
        deny all;
      }

      # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of the LAN
      location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
      }

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
      }

      error_page 404 /404.html;
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
        root /home/dani/asia-gazette;
      }
      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }
    }
  }
```

And my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 kiji.dev  eag.dev
```

In my /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file, I have the following:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0660
```

I've tried un-commenting the listen.mode and re-commenting but the result is the same. I restart nginx and php5-fpm and:

```
$ curl -v eag.dev
* Rebuilt URL to: eag.dev/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to eag.dev (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: eag.dev
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.6.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.0
< Date: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 15:57:06 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
<
* Connection #0 to host eag.dev left intact
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong and why Passenger will not show my Drupal app.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring NGINX to serve Ruby on Rails and Drupal websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959702/configuring-nginx-to-serve-ruby-on-rails-and-drupal-websites)

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I previously thought there was something wrong with my NGINX setup, but I do not believe this is the case. I can curl one app properly but not the other and it might have to do with php5-fps settings but I really am at a loss as to what I need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and frustration, I think I found the solution. Adding the following to `/etc/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf` seems to have done the trick:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```